# flutter popup is not coming to ask permission to access camera

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-camera

i try to request camera permission on real iphone to scan qr code using `qr_code_scanner` but the popup doesn't open i add `NSCameraUsageDescription` in `info.plist` and added in my `podfile` this

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',
     'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',
     'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',
     'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',
  ]
    end
  end 
end
```

and this my code for ask
i try this

```
getCamera() async {
   var status = await Permission.camera.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
  final result = await Permission.camera.request();
  if (result.isGranted) {
    setState(() {
    getPerm = true;
    });
  }
  } else {
  setState(() {
    getPerm = true;
  });
  }
}
```

and this

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(onLayoutDone);
 }
      void onLayoutDone(Duration timeStamp) async {
    _permissionStatus = await Permission.camera.status;
    if (_permissionStatus.isGranted) {
      setState(() {
        getPerm = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void _askCameraPermission() async {
    await Permission.camera.request();
    if (await Permission.camera.request().isGranted) {
      _permissionStatus = await Permission.camera.status;
      setState(() {
        getPerm = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

and call _askCameraPermission function on pressed in button
nothing of this ways is working with me and all Permission other than camera working

Comment: Maybe you already granted permission for the camera so pop up not opening

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your app on simulator or real device? [Here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/407) is the similar issue for you plugin.

Also you can try:

1. check camera availability for your app in app settings in iOS;
2. debug your app for check permission status.

Answer (score 0):

Comment these line

### 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

### 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

And check your info.plist as well

Answer (score 0):

so i just remove asking request function and it worked i don't know how but it worked